# UITableViewCell with a StackView inside with dynamically added WKWebViews and UIImageViews

Tags: ios, uitableview, webview, uistackview

As the title says, I'm trying to display the following layout:

[image: I'm not able to indent because of that I did a screenshot]

As you see, the dynamic stack view is a container where content is added dynamically. This content is variable and is decided on run time. Basically, it can be webviews (with variable content inside), ImageViews (with variable height), and videos (this view would have a fixed view).

I configured the CellView with automatic row height, and provided an estimated row height, both in code and in Xcode. Then on the tableView_cellForRow at the method of the ViewController, the cell is dequeued and the cell is rendered with content.

During this setup process, the different labels and views are filled with content, and the dynamic container too. The webviews are added to the stackview with the following code:

```
    var webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
    webView.navigationDelegate = myNavigationDelegate

    webView = addContentToWebView(content, webView)
    container.addArrangedSubview(webView)
```

I'm testing this with only a webview inside the stackview and having already problems with the height of the row.

The webview is rendered correctly inside the stackview, but not completely (the webview was bigger as the estimated rowheight). I used the navigation delegate to calculate the height of the added webview and resize the StackContainer accordingly, with the following code:

```
  webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState", completionHandler: { (complete, error) in
        if complete != nil {
            webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight", completionHandler: { (height, error) in
               
                let h = height as! CGFloat
                print("Height 3 is \(h)")
                self.dynamicContainerHeightContraint.constant = h

            })
        }
        
    })
```

And indeed, the stackcontainer is resized and expanded to match the height of the webview that is inside.

But the row remains with the same estimated height, and if the webview is very big in height, then all the other views disappear (they are pushed outside the bounds of the row.

Is there a way to tell the row to autoresize and adapt to its contents? Or maybe I'm using the false approach?

I suppose the problem is that the height of the views added to the stackview is not known in advance, but I was expecting a way to tell the row to recalculate its height after adding all the needed stuff inside...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table views do not automatically redraw their cells when a cell's content changes.

Since you are changing the constant of your cell's `dynamicContainerHeightContraint` *after* the cell has been rendered (your web view's page load is asynchronous), the table does not auto-update -- as you've seen.

To fix this, you can add a "callback" closure to your cell, which will let the cell tell the controller to recalculate the layout.

Here is a simple example to demonstrate.

The cell has a single label... it has a "label height constraint" var that initially sets the height of the label to 30.

For the 3rd row, we'll set a 3-second timer to simulate the delayed page load in your web view. After 3 seconds, the cell's code will change the height constant to 80.

Here's how it looks to start:

[image]

***Without*** the callback closure, here's how it looks after 3 seconds:

[image]

***With*** the callback closure, here's how it looks after 3 seconds:

[image]

And here's the sample code.

***DelayedCell*** UITableViewCell class

```
class DelayedCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    let myLabel = UILabel()
    var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    // closure to tell the controller our content changed height
    var callback: (() -> ())?
    
    var timer: Timer?
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        contentView.clipsToBounds = true
        
        myLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        contentView.addSubview(myLabel)
        
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        
        // we'll change this dynamically
        heightConstraint = myLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30.0)
        
        // use bottom anchor with Prioirty: 999 to avoid auto-layout complaints
        let bc = myLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor)
        bc.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain label to all 4 sides
            myLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            myLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            myLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            
            // activate bottom and height constraints
            bc,
            heightConstraint,
        ])
        
    }
    
    func fillData(_ str: String, testTimer: Bool) -> Void {
        
        myLabel.text = str
        
        // so we can see the label frame
        //  green if we're testing the timer in this cell
        //  otherwise yellow
        myLabel.backgroundColor = testTimer ? .green : .yellow
        
        if testTimer {
            // trigger a timer in 3 seconds to change the height of the label
            //  simulating the delayed load of the web view
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.heightChanged), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        }
    }
    
    @objc func heightChanged() -> Void {
        
        // change the height constraint
        heightConstraint.constant = 80
        
        myLabel.text = "Height changed to 80"

        // run this example first with the next line commented
        // then run it again but un-comment the next line
        
        // tell the controller we need to update
        //callback?()
        
    }
    
    override func willMove(toSuperview newSuperview: UIView?) {
        if newSuperview == nil {
            timer?.invalidate()
        }
    }
    
}
```

***DelayTestTableViewController*** UITableViewController class

```
class DelayTestTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(DelayedCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DelayedCell
        
        // we'll test the delayed content height change for row 2
        let bTest = indexPath.row == 2
        cell.fillData("Row \(indexPath.row)", testTimer: bTest)
        
        // set the callback closure
        cell.callback = { [weak tableView] in
            guard let tv = tableView else { return }
            // this will tell the tableView to recalculate row heights
            //  without reloading the cells
            tv.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)
        }
        
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

In *your* code, you would make the closure callback after this line:

```
self.dynamicContainerHeightContraint.constant = h
```